# Filtering a list and removing unwanted data C#

Tags: c#, list

I have a `list` of users for a `timespan`, for arguments sake let's say a month. So in that `list` certain users do not meet the criteria I want for a certain objective so I want to filter out the `list` and display the filtered out data into another `list`. So how I replicated the `list` was as follows:

```
List<tblList1> List1 = new XPQuery<tblList1>(session)
    .Where(w => w.UserCode != null).ToList();
```

I then use a `foreach` loop to go through this list to compare the data to my criteria and then add them to the new list which is working perfectly. The problem I now have is to delete the data I took from the first `list`. I tried the following in a new method which I created:

```
public void DeleteData(Session session)
{
    List<tblList1> List1= new XPQuery<tblList1>(session)
        .Where(w => w.UserID != null).ToList();

    List<tblList2> List2= new XPQuery<tblList2>(session)
        .Where(w => w.UserID!= null).ToList();

    List1.RemoveAll(w => w.UserID == List2.Any(e => e.UserID== w.UserID));
}
```

So in the end I want to remove all the data in list1 so that we can view the deleted data in list2. Any help would be appreciated if I can just get the RemoveAll LINQ statement correct as the current line does not work and I am unsure of how to handle this in LINQ.

Comment: `.Any()` returns boolean. You compare your `UserID` with boolean. As for me, it is actually still unclear what you are trying to achieve. What is `XPQuery`? May be, if you post your `foreach` which collects data by criteria, then it would be easier to understand.

Comment: You could Select UserID of List2 , so it is a list of userIds and then RemoveAll( w => Liste2.Contains(w.UserId) ) , am I right? _Or_ maybe there is, but I am not sure, something like "intersect" or "except" ? See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev, XPquery is just a XPO class part of the XAF framework. So rather than using .Any() what would you suggest as I tried using the .Where() and then just compare the UserID's? I'm going to try that to see if that works.

Comment: @Fildor You are correct yes. You just provided me with an idea. I could in theory while creating List2 remove the data from List1 before finalizing List2. So then I can use the List1.RemoveAll(w => w.userID == List2.UserID);

Comment: So you have `List1` (e.g. `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`) and you want to remove `List2` (e.g. `{2, 3, 7}`) from it and you want to get `List3` of actually deleted items (`{2, 3}` in the example). Is it your case?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, well not really. I want to take List1 {1, 2, 3} compare them to criteria and see that { 2 } does not meet that criteria and add that in List2. Then delete { 2 } from List1

Comment: But couldn't you include that in the first "Where" in the first place? And thus filter those out without the second list?

Comment: @RubenRedman So, something like this? `List<Item> all = ...; List<Item> matching = all.Where(x => IsMatching(x)).ToList(); List<Item> notMatching = all.Except(matching).ToList();`

Comment: @Fildor, it won't unfortunately work in the first where because the filter happens after the foreach loop. The foreach loop sets new properties I have in a new object. The where would not be able to cater for all the criteria I want to check.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev, I'll try that way and see if it works as well. Thanks.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev, the logic you mentioned work for me. You can maybe answer with your comment so I can just mark it as correct for any future user who would require it as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use LINQ `Where` to filter your list, and then `Except` to get unfiltered values:

```
List<Item> all = ...; // your original list
List<Item> matching = all.Where(x => IsMatching(x)).ToList(); // IsMatching is any filtering logic
List<Item> notMatching = all.Except(matching).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can see from comments:

> I want to take List1 {1, 2, 3} compare them to criteria and see that {
>   2 } does not meet that criteria and add that in List2. Then delete { 2
>   } from List1

I can't see any need in *Linq* at all. Let's fill *both* Lists in parallel:

```
List<tblList1> List1 = new List<tblList1>();
//TODO: please, check types; it seems that it should be List<tblList1> List2
List<tblList2> List2 = new List<tblList2>();

foreach (var item in new XPQuery<tblList1>(session).Where(w => w.UserID != null)) {
  if (YourCriteriaHere)
    List1.Add(item); // <- Criteria met: add to List1 
  else
    List2.Add(item); // <- Doesn't meet: "delete" from (just not add to) List1 into List2 
}
```